# My Xcode 4 Documentation from Organizer stuck in the "Sign in with your Apple ID" page

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode4

My Xcode 4 Documentation is stuck at the screen below:

[image: stuck]

This same thing happened after I updated Xcode a couple of weeks ago. Apparently I need to login, but there is no way to do so within Xcode's embedded browser.

Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: +1 - I've exactly this problem too. I have tried to log in on Safari but no difference.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same problem. To solve, I had to re-download the documentation. Press <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> then go to the Downloads tab and download it from there.

Comment: No, I've already have it. But it seems don't let me use until I login.

Comment: Try to login from Safari. Not sure, but maybe they share login info.

Comment: This is the correct answer, but to be a little clearer.. the problem is that you've got a preview documentation set loaded which has expired in some way. In XCode, go to preferences, click Downloads in the toolbar, click the Documentation tab, click the "Check and Install Now" button. (While you're here turn on the "Check and install updates automatically" checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, had to delete the documentation set and reinstall.

Comment: For anyone concerned, you have to click the disclosure icon in the bottom-left of the list view and follow the "Installed to" link. Delete it from your computer and then click the "Check and Install" link. That'll show the docs again and let you install them.